# execute script against sql server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, powershell, batch-file

I have a database script in a .sql file for sql server 2008 that I want to execute against my database. Rather this being a manual exercise, I would like to automate it. I have 3 options available to me, a batch file, powershell or c#. The way I execute this will be influenced by my next question - I want to execute the script but also be aware in code if the script fails to execute for any reason? This will be part of a general set of install steps so want the install to halt if the script does not execute correctly.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the SQL Agent?

Comment: How is the rest of your installation process handled?

Comment: It currently is a batch file that handles the installation process but will to change as part of response to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Run it as a SQL agent job, you can set SQL agent to send you alerts if the script fails.

Comment: I want it automated as part of an installation process as said in question.

Comment: @amateur, you can automate SQL Agent jobs. They can be created with a bunch of system procs `sp_add_job` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the SQLCMD utility?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following are the process to automate the script through installer in c#

**Code in c#**

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string expression = "Parameter value";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (dr.Read()) {
        }
    }
}
```

In you project add a installer class Reference => [Installer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx)

```
You can find below mentioned events for the installer process.
1. Install
2. Commit
3. Rollback
4. UNInstall
```

write down the database connectivity and script execution code  in the above event. IN case the installer fails to execute the script exception will come and control will automatically move to the rollback event. So finally the rollback event will tell the user that the installation could not be done due to failure in executing the script...

Answer (score 0):

You could try SQL Server Management Objects (SMO - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx), this should work in your scenario, executing sql script during installation process.

In this short code you can see how to connect to SQL server instance, here the Windows Authentication is used, but you can also use SQL Authentication by supplying connection.Login and connection.Password with your credentials. 
After that event handlers are set up which can fire during (*ServerMessage*, *InfoMessage*) and after (*StatementExecuted*) script execution. Using both *ServerMessage* and *InfoMessage* here is an overkill since *ServerMessage* will also show Informational messages (error severity <10 in SQL), but it's good to see the way it works.

In this example textBox1.Text contains a T-SQL script which is executed with this line:
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(textBox1.Text);
Execute statement is surrounded with a try...catch to catch any errors during execution.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection("stjepan-lap");
        connection.LoginSecure = true;
        Server server = new Server(connection);
        server.ConnectionContext.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(ConnectionContext_InfoMessage);
        server.ConnectionContext.StatementExecuted += new StatementEventHandler(ConnectionContext_StatementExecuted);
        server.ConnectionContext.ServerMessage += new ServerMessageEventHandler(ConnectionContext_ServerMessage);

        //Executes T-Sql script
        try
        {
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

        server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
    }

    void ConnectionContext_ServerMessage(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
    }

    void ConnectionContext_StatementExecuted(object sender, StatementEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.SqlStatement);
    }

    void ConnectionContext_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

You should reference SMO dlls and put appropriate usings in your code file

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll 
....
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
```

Answer (score 0):

batch is easier i think (but that is a preference)

runsqlscr.cmd

```
@echo off
REM :: building your script below, not needed if already created
REM echo Select * from PutTableHere where > %temp%\tmpsql.sql
REM echo "put rest of sql script here one line at a time" >> %temp%\tmpsql.sql
REM echo go >> %temp%\tmpsql.sql
REM echo.
REM echo script written
REM echo.
REM echo ready to execute script
REM :: delete pause if needed
REM pause
REM :: the actual command needed in script
REM sqlcmd -U thedbuser -P thepasswd -d thedbname -o resultsofscript.txt < %temp%\tmpsql.sql 
REM echo All done, displaying results
REM type resultofscript.txt
REM echo.
```

you can skip the building of the script if it is already done, just change %temp%tmpsql.sql 
 to the location and name of your script.

on the sqlcmd line, you need to put in your own values for "the*"

the above is for testing, all you need for your installation script is the sqlcmd line.

happy batching

Answer (score -1):

You can also pack this in stored procedure and there use some error handling.

Comment: This can't be included as part of an installation process.

Answer (score -1):

- Run by sqlcmd.exe bootstrapper - harder to handle errors
- run by your own custom application - easiest way to handle errors and raise alerts

Comment: It's part of an installation process so none of these options are applicable.